# Работа с Activity после получения данных из сокета

Tags: android, сокет, парсер, callback

У меня есть класс, который подключен к сокету и постоянно получает от него данные. Я их разделяю на отдельные команды и передаю парсеру. 
Вопрос заключается вот в чем: в своей Ativity при нажатии на элемент списка я отправляю команду серверу (запрос на получение информации об этом элементе списка), запускаю активити, и после получения парсером ответной команды (json с данными) должен заполнить текстовые поля полученой информацией. 
Как можно реализовать механизм заполнения полей только после получения команды?

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.
Так а чем они будут заполнятсья без данных?
По приходу json'а вызываете метод, который заполняет все поля.

```
public void JSONCallback(Json json){
    SomeClass smth= new Gson().fromJson(json, SomeClass.class);
    textView.setText(smth.getText());
    //etc..
}
```

Если необходимо, то делаете поля недоступными для редактирования после нажатия кнопки, а в методе JSONCallback делаете их доступными

Comment: в парсере вызываю JSONCallback() в который передаю уже готовые значения для TextView, на строке setText(...) появляется ошибка: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать метод setText(...) в другом, не UI, потоке, или использовать AsyncTask, или Handler  [Источник](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: пробовал уже все, вылетает все та же ошибка